# JavaScript redirect not saving in history

Tags: javascript, redirect, cookies, browser-history

Here is the situation:

- I have a script it checks if there is a cookie if not it creates one and redirects to the page `b.com`
- On `b.com` I use `history.go(-1);`
- However I get immediately redirected to `b.com` again
- But this should not happen because `a.com` only redirect when cookie is not set. But now cookie is set it still redirects me. I probably never get back to `a.com`
- When I manually go to `a.com` I don't get redirected (because cookie is set)

The problem is no matter what direction I use it is kind of not saved in the (back-button) history. Only if I have a link on page `a.com` and click manually on it or a form (with `action="b.com"`) and submit it manually then get redirected to `b.com` now `history.go(-1)` works.

Comment: The redirection does use `window.location.replace()`?

Comment: No this does not work. However sometimes it kind of does work, when I visited a page before a.com then I get redirect from b.com to the page before a.com